# Nested With() in Laravel Model Collection Return

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a collection that is returned as such:

```
$scheduleLoads = Load::with('shipment','driver','tractor');
```

Now, my question is related to the with issue - is there a way to add the relationships of these relationships into my returned collection?

For example:

In the `Load` model I have the following relationship to `shipment`:

```
public function shipment(){
    return $this->belongsTo(shipment::class, 'shipmentID');
}
```

In the `shipment` model I have the following relationship:

```
public function shiptoAccount(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'ship_to');
}
```

Is there a way to include the shiptoAccount return of the `shipment` associated with the Loads collections?

Comment: Do you mean `Load::with('shipment.shiptoAccount','driver','tractor');`?

Comment: I'll add this above, but my relationship to the `shipment` is as such from my `Load` model:     public function shipment(){
        return $this->belongsTo(shipment::class, 'shipmentID');
    }

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Wow, that made me feel a bit a bit dull... thank you so much! I was curious, just for future reference, how would I include another? Would I have to go out and write `'shipment.shiptoAccount','shipment.shipfromAccount', ...` or some other way?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. I appreciate it! If you want, I'd be more than happy to select your answer if you post it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "dot" syntax ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)):

```php
$scheduleLoads = Load::with('shipment.shiptoAccount', 'driver', 'tractor');
```